# LWC Treegrid how do I hide headers or columns

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningtreegrid, slds-styling-hooks

I'm having a hard time figuring out styling for the lightning-tree-grid. [I want to implement this styling.](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tree-grid/#Headless-with-no-borders) and hide my id column. I tried adding classes to the grid and to columns but nothing happens. The documentation is all in HTML tables, nothing about how to add the classes to a lightning-tree-grid.

```
.html
         <lightning-tree-grid 
            data={gridData}
            columns={gridColumns}
            key-field="id"
            expanded-rows={expandedRows}
            >
        </lightning-tree-grid>
```

.js

```
get gridColumns() {
    return [
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'pageName',
            label: 'Page Name',
            initialWidth: 600,
        },
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'id',
            label: 'Id',
            initialWidth:10,
            class:'slds-hide'
        }

    ];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In lightning-tree-grid its more about the way your data are organized that formating

like in this salesforce example
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/example

[image]

the _children in the object that will create the dependency.
If you dont wanna some field you will need remove him from the EXAMPLES_COLUMNS_DEFINITION_BASIC and if you need some other time get by the id in the gridData

if you need to suppress the field only in the child you need to delete the info in the gridData(you can save an unedited one for searching purposes)

Answer (score 0):

**What we can do straight away**

Hiding the "id" column is possible: We just don't need to add it to the columns specification. There is no obligation to add a column specification for the "key-field".

And labels can be "" (i.e. a 0-length string). But this doesn't make the header line disappear.

To pass "class" into a column definition is impossible: The list of possible parameters is circumscribed by the list presented under "Working with Column Properties" [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/documentation). Anything else is ignored.

---

Figuring out if a specific layout characteristic is possible for components of Salesforce's component library, happens in steps. These steps are sorted according to increasing complexity, ease of maintanance, etc. If I succeed in one step, I don't look any further:

**1. Does adding a class to the component achieve what is needed?**

- This generally only impacts the way the component appears relative to others. E.g. a lightning-button can meaningfully [have a "slds-m-left_medium" class attached to it](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-components-css-variants.html). "Headless with no borders" is nothing like that.

**2. Does the component "Specification" list an attribute that let me tweak the default appearance?**

- No attribute comes even close to "Headless with no borders" in [the "Specification" for tree grids](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/specification). E.g. no "variant" attribute. Despite making use of data-table, tree-grid doesn't expose data-table's "hide-table-header" attribute.

**3. [Are there slots](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-components-slots.html) that I can use to hand over sections of rendered HTML "my style"?**

- Not for tree grids, see the "Documentation" section of the documentation. (For an example with slots, see e.g. [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tile/documentation); note that the "Specification" section omits stated slots. The documentation is not overly consistent. E.g. data-tables have actually a slot "customdatatypes", but this is not documented in the data-table spec.)

**4. What [styling hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/) are available?**

- The [blueprint of the tree-grid](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tree-grid/) doesn't have a "Styling Hooks Overview" like [other components](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/buttons/#Styling-Hooks-Overview), because it's not elementary enough - it's based on datatable, but even datatable is not elementary enough. We are therefore unlikely to find anything in the documentation coming close to "Headless with no borders".
- Scanning the rendered HTML for `var(--slds-c...)` yields neither anything to hide the header line. We can adjust colour and background colour of the header line though. And we can make the borders disappear by adding this to the CSS:

```css
:host {
    --slds-g-color-neutral-base-95: white;
    --slds-g-color-neutral-base-30: white;
    --lwc-borderWidthThin: 0;
}
```

As for the header section - we already came that close by setting labels to "". It's still a bit heigher than expected. So what can be done about the height of the header?

**5. Has Salesforce published the source code of the component, for me to copy it into my projects and modify it?**

- Unfortunately [not](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes#documentation).

**6. How simple is it to take the component blueprint and add my one's own Javascript?**

- [Looking at the attached code](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tree-grid/#Headless-with-no-borders), (and considering the functionality the tree-grid provides), it looks rather like work. Is it really worth it?!

Comment: That is disappointing. It seems like a real lack on Salesforce's side to not have a clear example how to implement the SLDS designs in LWC.

Comment: There can only be examples to the degree something is possible. It's not possible to pass style (or class) directives into child components. This is by design: Web components (Lightning or not) prevent the outside world from any influence on their rendering. You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM). Any exception from this rule must be explicitly stated in the component set up, e.g. by a public API or styling hooks. My hope was that above gives you enough options to realize almost everything wanted.

Comment: I talked to Salesforce support and the response is "we're working on it." I've created an ideas to help keep this on the radar. I appreciate your response @Felix van Hove, it clarified that there really is a gap here.